# Cannot access container by "network_mode: host"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, home-assistant

I cannnot use `network_mode: host` in docker in `windows 10`. I try difference images, it cannot too.

I post my `docker-compose.yaml` below.

docker-compose.yaml

```
  homeassistant2:
    container_name: hass2
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant:0.112.2
    network_mode: host
```

But when set the port mapping,everthing is fine

```
   ports:
      - '8123:8123'
   # network_mode: host
```

My environmet is **windows 10**

I get some information from command **docker inspect**

I post some of it  about network settings below.

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "f084a1e7e4966f0bff678e4120c1bcbc7afdd1c55d5164b1dc4a606470c43bcc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "656b532cdc48c9e34e616ec0a38ef944c5e52e2dfca506ca99e53b4b16206000",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

If I need provide something else to analyze the problem, please tell me.

Comment: On what platform (Linux/Mac OS/Windows) are you running Docker?

Comment: Thanks, bro.That's in windows 10.

Comment: If deleting `network_mode: host` works, that's probably the right answer: that option generally disables Docker's networking and you shouldn't typically need it.

Answer (score 8):

When running Docker under Windows or MacOS, you're actually running Docker in a Linux virtual machine. When you set `network_mode: host`, you're connecting the container to the network environment of the virtual machine. This is seldom going to be useful.

`network_mode: host` is really only going to make sense when running Docker natively on Linux.

You're better off sticking with port publishing.

Comment: The what is the usual recomendations when developing stuff in, e.g., windows? I am currently facing an issue that is caused by the use of the default mode `bridge` and I should to switch to `host` to avoid it. In this case is recommended to switch my development OS to Linux?

Comment: I don't know enough about your specific situation to offer a recommendation. It might be worth opening a new question with a description of the problem you're trying to solve.